# Format validation regex on model is triggered if the value is blank when it shouldnt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a fairly simple form.

```
<%= form_for([@category_item_value], url: create_category_item_value_path(key_id: item_key.id), method: :post) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= f.label :stat %> 
      <%= f.text_field :value, :value => item_key.value %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :key_type, :value => 'item-edit-request' %>
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

With this model

```
 validates :key, length: { maximum: 255 },
  exclusion: { in: %w( create edit new update ), message: "%{value} cant be taken." },
 format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\z/, message: "only allows letters, numbers and '-'" }


 validates :value, length: { maximum: 65000 }
```

When I submit the form the `key` value is left blank or nil in the DB because it is added in later. Problem is that I cant submit the form because the format validation on key stops me with the error message "only allows letters, numbers and '-'".

Why does it do this, I dont have a `presence: :true` validation on `key` but I cant let it be blank because of the format validation. This wasnt ever a problem and the form used to work fine, it was only until recently that I went over it again and notices the form wasn't submitting.

Why would this start happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add the `allow_blank` option, otherwise your regexp indeed will not match and the format validation will fail. See the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#common-validation-options) for validation options common to all validations.

So, the following should work:

```
validates :key, length: { maximum: 255 },
                exclusion: { in: %w( create edit new update ), message: "%{value} cant be taken." },
                format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\z/, 
                          allow_blank: true,
                          message: "only allows letters, numbers and '-'" }
```

Another possibility is to change the regexp to optional characters (with `*` instead of `+`), like this:

```
 ...
 with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\z/ ,
 ...
```

Comment: The latter is more explicit, IMHO.

Comment: I agree, OTOH I find the former option more easily readable (easier to spot on first glance).

Comment: Can I add both allow nil and allow blank?

Comment: Technically yes, but it makes no sense - `blank?` includes `nil?` because `nil.blank?` is `true`. So `allow_blank` should suffice in your case, if all you want is to allow blank strings. Sorry, I updated the answer so that it does not lead to this confusion.